# Blender Crashes seconds after startup

Tags: command-line

{Lenoveo Ideapad 330, Windows 10, Intel core i5-825U @1.60 GHz 1.80 GHz, 8 GB RAM, Intel UH Graphics 620}

Hello friends,

I downloaded blender today to try it out. When I launch the program, the blender window opens and I can begin rotating the cube and can open menus, but after apx 1-minute, blender abruptly closes. I tried launching it and doing nothing, not touching anything, and I timed how long it stayed open - just over 1-minute.

After reading several bug posts on this forum, I launched blender and immediately opened the console window via Window>Toggle System Console. Now that the console window is open, blender hasn't crashed. It has been open for a short while now.

Any suggestions? Why does the console window keep blender from crashing? I have a feeling this isn't the end of the problem.

-Greg

Comment: It would be helpful to know, which version of Blender you are actually running, as 2.8 is still in beta and therefore a little unreliable.

Comment: It is version 2.79b

Comment: blender stayed open for several hours, but I was away from my desk for most of that time. Now I sat down to begin learning how to use it with a Blender Guru tutorial. After a few minutes of playing around, I decided to close Blender & restart it to see if it would continue to work. BIG MISTAKE!. Now when I launch Blender & open a console as well, Blender closes after 1-minute. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: I am not much in the way of an IT-Support guy, but the usual order in which one would go is: restart program, restart OS, un-install/re-install program.

You could also try sifting through your error logs to see, what Blender is colliding with on your machine. You can do this with the "Event Viewer". I'll link you to an explanation, just in case. https://kb.blackbaud.co.uk/articles/Article/75433